# How to make links with target="_blank" open tab in current window?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Using Firefox 3.6.8, if I have two or more windows open and I click a link with target="_blank", it always opens the link in a new tab in the **first** window.
How can I make it so these links always open in a new tab **in the window they were launched from**?

I have tried the "Tab Mix Plus" addon, and couldn't find a way to do it with that.

Comment: This is a prime example why links with `target="_blank"` suck. I'm glad this part of HTML is depreciated. Users should always have control over where pages open.

Comment: And how to have Firefox open these links **normally** ?

Answer (score 4):

Surf to about:config

[browser.link.open_newwindow set to 3](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow)

This should be the default. No idea why your setting was different. Perhaps you have a plugin that is messing with the behaviour?

Comment: That is exactly what mine is set to, and it doesn't do what I want. Links with target="_blank" are always opening a tab in the first browser window, not necessarily the window the link was launched from.

Answer (score 2):

- Bring up the Options Dialog box.
- Select the tab screen.
- Make sure open new windows in a new tab instead is selected and click ok.

You might also want to look at the setting

[browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction)

Comment: I have the option set to open windows in a new tab. I've tried the three documented values for browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction in about:config; none of them produce the desired effect.